# NSLocationAlwaysUsageDescription/NSLocationWhenInUseUsageDescription: where to put translations

Tags: ios, xcode, ios8, localization

My app supports 3 different languages: EN, DE, FR
As `NSLocationAlwaysUsageDescription` / `NSLocationWhenInUseUsageDescription` are defined in `Info.plist`, I am wondering where I put the values for DE and FR.
Any ideas?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

In order to translate `Info.plist` to the 3 languages, you would need to create a `InfoPlist.strings` file in each of the following directories :

- `en.lproj`
- `fr.lproj`
- `de.lproj`

The 3 files should have the following content :

```
NSLocationWhenInUseUsageDescription = "YOUR TEXT HERE";
NSLocationAlwaysUsageDescription = "YOUR TEXT HERE";
```

Since the files won't show up automatically in Xcode's Project Navigator, you have to manually add them to the project bundle, this can be achieved via right-clicking the project name in Xcode and choosing the `Add files to X` option, then selecting the files you just created.

---

Also if you want to test the result & make sure things work, changing the `Application Language` in `Edit Scheme > Run > Options` isn't enough.

You need to change the *simulator* or the *device* language via `Settings > General > Language & Region > iPhone Language`